# How to get an ssh socks proxy on demand?

Tags: ssh, netcat, socks-proxy, socat

I know `ssh` provides a SOCKS proxy with `-D`. I wonder if it's possible to start such a proxy on demand, the moment a connection is made to a specified port (using the likes of `socat` and `nc` under the hood). This is a single-user machine, so no authentication of local connections is needed.

Here is what I tried:

- Tell the web browser to use a SOCKS proxy at `localhost:portA`.
- For each connection to the "trigger" port `portA`, `socat` calls the `nc-ssh-socks` script, which eventually exec-s into `nc localhost portB`:

  ```
  socat TCP-LISTEN:portA,fork EXEC:"nc-ssh-socks server portB"
  ```
- The script also makes sure an `ssh` process exists that's providing the SOCKS proxy at `localhost:portB`:

  ```
  cmd="ssh -fND $2 $1"
  pgrep -u $USER -fx "$cmd" || $cmd
  exec nc localhost $2
  ```

However, the scheme doesn't work, I keep getting errors from `socat -ddddd` of the form:

```
W read(6, 0x1bf5360, 8192): Connection reset by peer
W waitpid(): child 25032 exited with status 1
E write(6, 0x1bf5360, 2): Broken pipe
```

Strangely, occasionally I see parts of a page showing up in the browser, but I don't know if that's because of caching or because some connections work but most don't.

Does anyone know enough about `socat`, `nc`, and `ssh` to understand why this is not working?

Comment: What is the point? In what way(s) is this idea better than `ssh -ND …` (possibly run via `autossh`) that listens on `portA` all the time?

Answer (score 0):

While debugging, increase your visibility by removing -fN from your ssh command and add -vvv to for debug info. This will only give you client side info, but may tell you more.